# list comprehension multiplying itself, and it isn't checking according to conditionals

Tags: python

I am trying to fix my condition that says if found any `forbidden` keyword in string or string_2 then skip it, but if not found any keyword from forbidden, but it found any word from `skills` then save it, but however it is `multiplying` the results `10` times in the `else` part.

```py
string = "opportunity: this opportunity would suit a budding hacker who is seeking a first step into a commercial role or a tester with 1-3 years of experience. this is a great opportunity to utilise your experience in penetration testing, vulnerability assessments and delivering outcomes while also expanding your knowledge and skillset. benefits: perform red team engagements excellent training & development budget attendance at local and international conferences responsibilities include: working with a diverse range of customers identify and solve security problems perform penetration testing and vulnerability assessments maintain and improve penetration testing and methodologies delivery of technical reports and documentation ideally you will have: ideally current security clearance or minimum australian citizenship certifications such as oscp, sans, crest highly regarded fluent with linux command line and windows powershell experience performing assessments on client networks ability to clearly communicate vulnerability details and risks for a confidential discussion about this opportunity or to discuss other opportunities within it security & risk please contact specialist infosec recruiter john smith on 0123 456 789 or email johnsmith@example.com. australian citizens only – ideally already with a security clearance. want to know more about me? connect with me on linkedin"
string_2 = "your new company this melbourne based consultancy boasts a unique depth and breadth of capabilities across cyber security, application security, data & analytics, cloud and digital transformations. they continue to deliver rich insight, innovative strategies and solutions that help their clients reach their potential. about the opportunity this is an outstanding opportunity to utilise your experience in penetration testing and vulnerability assessments. you will use your skills to prepare high quality reports detailing security issues, making recommendations and identifying solutions. the types of testing can include vulnerability assessment, penetration testing and application security assessment. what you’ll need to succeed passion, drive and enthusiasm! demonstrated experience performing internal and external penetration testing, web application penetration testing and mobile application penetration testing industry certifications such as sans, oscp, crest crt/cct or osce strong knowledge of common vulnerabilities such as owasp top 10 and sans top 25 scripting experience - javascript, objective c and python a very strong technical background and a passion for security the ability to think outside the box what you'll get in return our client is looking for an individual that is seeking longevity in their next role and in return offers the chance to join an equal opportunity employer that is passionate about diversity. also on offer is ongoing personal and professional development, providing you with the right tools and support to thrive. what you need to do now if you’re interested in this role, click ‘apply now’ or for more information and a confidential discussion on this role or any others within it security contact john smith at johnsmith@example.com"
forbidden = ['clearance','TS/SCI','4+ years','5+ years','6+ years','7+ years','8+ years','9+ years','10+ years','11+ years','12+ years']
skills = ['owasp']

for s_prefix in forbidden:
    if s_prefix in string:
        print(s_prefix)
    else:
        print("save it")


skill_match = [s_prefix for s_prefix in forbidden if s_prefix in string]

print(skill_match)

if len(skill_match) > 0 :
    pass
```

I am getting the output of multiples times `save it` while once it found `clearance` it should be marked as flagged, and if it doesn't found any red-flagged keyword, and any keyword from `skills` then save

```
clearance
save it
save it
save it
save it
save it
save it
save it
save it
save it
save it
['clearance']
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

sample:

```
string = "snip active cleared snip..." # skip or remove because contains cleared
string2 = "snip owasp..... php , devops" # save it because contains owasp
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. For each word in `forbidden` it prints `"save it"` if it is not in `string`. The only word from `forbidden` in `string` is `"clearence"`... where is the problem?

Comment: I don't want to save if any of the `forbidden` is found in `string` , but if it doesn't exits any keywords from `forbidden` , and exits `skills` then save it

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to acheive. Try to explain in more detail and maybe add a sample output

Comment: I added an example what I am trying to achieve

Comment: You already have `[s_prefix for s_prefix in forbidden if s_prefix in string]` which gives you the matching `forbidden` words. So if you want to know whether to reject the string on that basis, all you need to do is see whether that list is empty. Then you can use the same trick to find whether there are any of the `skills`. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @jzz_joker please undelete your most recent question. I had an answer I was hoping to post although I saw you deleted it hastily it seems. Unless you have found your answer then Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one line to be printed in your `for` loop, you probably need to change its logic, since currently it *always* prints something on every iteration.

One approach might be to print and `break` out of the loop if you spot one of the strings you're searching for, and to attach the `else` clause to the `for` loop instead of to the `if`. An `else` on a loop gets run only if the loop ended normally, not if it was escaped early by a `break`:

```
for s_prefix in forbidden:
    if s_prefix in string:
        print(s_prefix)
        break
else:
    print("save it")
```

If you don't need to print the matching prefix string, you could also play around with `any` or `all`.

Comment: if I want to use this version as a linear comprehension how can I do it?

Comment: There's no good way to get this into list comprehension form, unfortunately. But you don't really want a list comprehension, since you want only one value, not one per forbidden string. (And by the way, it's "list comprehension" not "linear comprehension", the latter doesn't mean anything.)

Comment: the value it will change because it will be replaced by a given list in this case was an example to dynamic array